# StorageFolder File Not Found error

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am having some issues in my app that can download a list of music files. I'm trying to setup the following folder structure. Music Library > Artist(s) > Release Name. When starting the download, the first song's folder structure is setup properly. Once the second download starts, I always get a File Not found exception when trying to create the second sub folder (release name). Here is my code.

```
    private async Task StartDownload(List<DownloadData> data)
    {
        foreach (DownloadData song in data)
        {
            // Set the source of the download
            Uri source = new Uri(song.downloadUrl);

            // Create folder stucture
            StorageFolder artistFolder;
            try
            {
                artistFolder = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFolderAsync(song.artistName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            StorageFolder releaseFolder;
            try
            {
                releaseFolder = await artistFolder.CreateFolderAsync(song.releaseName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw; // Exception Thrown here
            }

            // Create file
            StorageFile destinationFile;
            try
            {
                destinationFile = await releaseFolder.CreateFileAsync(song.fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);

            List<DownloadOperation> requestOperations = new List<DownloadOperation>();
            requestOperations.Add(download);

            await HandleDownloadAsync(download, true);
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why it works the first time around but fails on the second song.

Comment: Why do you have so many `catch{throw;}`.  Either catch and do something or don't catch at all.

Comment: @juharr i don't know how to handle the exception. Thats why i'm asking this question.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227257.aspx) `CreateFileAsync` throws `FileNotFoundException` if "The folder name contains invalid characters, or the format of the folder name is incorrect."  So what is the value of `song.releaseName`?

Comment: Good catch. The release name has a couple of "/" in it.  Would my only option be to remove those then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227257.aspx) for `CreateFileAsync` it will throw `FileNotFoundExcption` if

> The folder name contains invalid characters, or the format of the folder name is incorrect.

So you likely need to replace invalid characters with something else like underscore.

```
var fixedFolderName = string.Join(
    "_", 
    song.releaseName.Split(Path.GetInvaildFileNameChars()));
```

Comment: Using `GetInvalidPathChars()` won't replace the "/" for some reason, but switching that to `GetInvaildFileNameChars()` fixes the issue.

Comment: Yeah "/" is a valid path character, specifically the path separator.  I thought that was more like `GetInvalidFolderChars()`, but the file name one is what you actually want.